# Remove non-numeric characters form getLatLng() function

Tags: leaflet, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I'm using Leaflet API. I'm using the Leaflet Draw plugin to select areas on the map. I need to set up a bounding box using leaflet draw to send to GeoServer.

The problem is when I use the following code:

```
var coords = the_layer.getLatLngs()[0];
```

I get the coordinates back like this:

```
LatLng(43.13306, -112.71973),LatLng(45.02695, -112.71973),LatLng(45.02695, -106.3916),LatLng(43.13306, -106.3916)
```

I need them back in this format (minx,miny,maxx,maxy):

```
-109.46777343750001,47.96050238891509,-108.58886718750001,48.16608541901253
```

So I need all of the non-numeric characters (excluding the commas) removed. I also need all spaces removed.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaflet layers have methods to calculate a bounding box, and convert it to a string for sending to web services:

`var coords = the_layer.getBounds().toBBoxString();`

Comment: That's whacky. I swear i tried that and it said "toBBoxString() is not a funciton".  That works now...Thanks!